# Is it neccessary to use kthread_stop if we return from kernel thread?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

If I have the following kernel thread function:

```
int thread_fn() {
    printk(KERN_INFO "In thread1");    
    return 0;
}
```

Do I still need to use `kthread_stop()` function here?

Will `return` in the thread function make the kernel thread stop and exit?

Comment: I guess you should be able to tell by looking at the code that starts a thread, and seeing if it sets up the thread's stack with a return address that would go somewhere sane.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at how `kthread()` is [implemented](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/kthread.c?v=4.4#L177), at line 209 it calls `threadfn(data)` and stores the exit code in `ret`; then it calls `do_exit(ret)`.

So a simple return from your `threadfn` is sufficient.

If you look at the documentation of [kthread_stop](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/device-drivers/API-kthread-stop.html), it says that it:

- sets `kthread_should_stop` to return true;
- wakes the thread;
- waits for the thread to exit.

This means that `kthread_stop()` should be only called from outside a thread to stop the thread. Since it waits for the thread to finish, you must not call this inside the thread or you might deadlock!

Moreover, the documentation says that it only informs the thread that it should exit, and that the thread should call `kthread_should_stop` to find out about this. So a long-lived `threadfn` might do this:

```
int thread_fn() {
    printk(KERN_INFO "In thread1");
    while (!kthread_should_stop()) {
        get_some_work_to_do_or_block();
        if (have_work_to_do())
            do_work();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But if your function is not long-lived, calling `kthread_should_stop` is not necessary.